# Schema.org ferry port

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I am looking to create a JSON-LD piece of structured data to describe a ferry port.

As far as I can see on schema.org, the only transport hubs available are airports and bus depots and land vehicle terminals.

What would be the correct format to describe a ferry port, and similarly a ferry journey?